# filter returns an empty array while looping an object's property (array of objects)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, filter

I can't understand why do filter returns an empty array when I try to loop through the object's array property.

Though, When I try to do console.log(this.users) inside the getFilteredUsers method, I can see the filter method inside its proto...

```
var userService = {
  currentFilter: "active",
  users: [
    { name: "Alex", status: "active" },
    { name: "Nick", status: "deleted" }
  ],
  getFilteredUsers: function() {
    // console.log(this.users);
    return this.users.filter(function(user) {
      return user.status === this.currentFilter;
    });    
  }
};

console.log(userService.getFilteredUsers()); // []
```

Comment: add .bind(this) after `function(user) {...}`

Comment: Chris, can you give me an example please? I'm trying to do it but fail.

Comment: this.users.filter(function(user) {
      return user.status === this.currentFilter;
    }.bind(this))

Comment: Damn, I did it after changing it to arrow function )) Thanks!

Comment: Guys, can you please give me some resources so I could getting such knowledges? A lot of courses show how to operate with JS stuffs but they don't go deep to underwater rocks.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of value of

> this

in filter callback. Use arrow function to get correct value for this

```js
var userService = {
  currentFilter: "active",
  users: [
    { name: "Alex", status: "active" },
    { name: "Nick", status: "deleted" }
  ],
  getFilteredUsers: function() {
    // console.log(this.users);
    return this.users.filter((user)=> {
      return user.status === this.currentFilter;
    });    
  }
};

console.log(userService.getFilteredUsers()); // []
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the scope of **this** object. It changes inside the **callback** function of **filter()**. There are two ways you can try:

1. Create a new filter variable in your function before filter callback function, something like:

```js
var userService = {
    currentFilter: "active",
    users: [{
            name: "Alex",
            status: "active"
        },
        {
            name: "Nick",
            status: "deleted"
        }
    ],
    getFilteredUsers: function() {
        const currentStatus = this.currentFilter;
        return this.users.filter(function(user) {
            return user.status === currentStatus;
        });
    }
};

console.log(userService.getFilteredUsers()); //[ { name: 'Alex', status: 'active' } ]
```

2. Use es6 **arrow** function:

```js
var userService = {
    currentFilter: "active",
    users: [{
            name: "Alex",
            status: "active"
        },
        {
            name: "Nick",
            status: "deleted"
        }
    ],
    getFilteredUsers: function() {
        return this.users.filter(({
            status
        }) => status === this.currentFilter);
    }
};

console.log(userService.getFilteredUsers()); // [ { name: 'Alex', status: 'active' } ]
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yeah! It's really helpfull, thank you! I also have tried to use something like const _this = this before using filter function, but I think that this is not a best practice )

Comment: Glad it helps, happy coding :)